# vscode: PERM: operation not permitted, copyfile

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Im getting this error and tried asking on vscode github, but it directed me here..

I have my project on google drive and i can open fine in vscode. i can create files and run them fine.   However, when i try to copy a file from one folder to  another in vscode, i get the error:

`The file(s) to paste have been deleted or moved since you copied them. Error: EPERM: operation not permitted`

One thing im noticing is the folders show a cloud icon when i look at them in Windows File Explorer:

[image]

Additionally if i hover over a folder, i see the tooltip popup showing it as empty, when in fact it is not.  This may be because i have setup google drive to stream files.  So it sounds like perhaps vscode is thinking the files dont exist as well, much like windows explorer.
If i click into the folder i see the files there and can open them fine.   if do that and try again in vscode (assumption is that the files will be'downloaded' locally), still does not work

Anyone run into this issue and know how to resolve?

Comment: how are you manipulating your google drive through VS Code? Something like a network drive mounted on filesystem? VS Code extension?

Comment: i have installed google drive for desktop.  it adds a 'G:' drive to my system.  my projects are located on that 'drive'.   in vscode i simly navigate to the project folder on that drive and open it.  In most cases i have not had issues w/ this setup...

Comment: you might want to consider raising an issue ticket. You can use the `Help > Report Issue` function of VS Code. If you do, please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.